# MPAndroidChart Pull to refresh horizontal

Tags: android, pull-to-refresh

Somebody can help me solve this problem.I need implements pull to refresh https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh in horizontal to Android MPChart:https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart . Sorry for my bad English,thanks for help!

Comment: Please share your current workaround and describe exactly your problem

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: I'm following this file: https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartExample/src/com/xxmassdeveloper/mpchartexample/LineChartActivity1.java , and i need pull to refresh like chart of this app:https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/simpleweight-simple-powerful/id418785500?mt=8 . Sorry because my English to bad so i can not describe more.

Answer (score 0):

Put your chart inside this one, implement OnRefreshListener and setOnRefreshListener():
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout.html